# Зачем нужен @PathVariable в методе PUT?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

Нигде не нашёл информацию стоит ли указывать явно  `id`.

**Код:**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value="/update/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public User updateUser(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody User user){
    Assert.isTrue(user.getId().equals(id), "User Id must match Url Id");
    return svc.updateUser(id, user);
}
```

Во многих примерах не видел даже того, чтобы был `@PathVariable long id` - хотя при этом некоторые личности утверждают, что `id` в пути указывать *нужно*, не понимаю зачем? Можно ли сразу указывать `id`  в сущности ? Для чего нужен `@PathVariable`? Я понимаю, что если бы мы пользовались чистым SQL, но здесь же везде JPA?

Comment: Не patch (заплатка), а path - путь. Path variable - это один из способов передачи параметра запроса, в ваше случае это id в пути, т.е. запрос должен прийти на путь `/update/111`, и это 111 попадет в параметр id. В каких случаях лепить - это как вам удобнее, как спроектируете API.

Answer (score 1):

В соответствие с REST логикой маппинга адресов в метод PUT передается параметр ид. объекта, который надо обновить.

Так мы по крайней мере знаем какой объект обновляется, а вот каким объектом это не важно. Так мы можем один объект замещать другим, или по крайней мере не будет обновления всей базы (если ид. объекта отсутствует).

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе не нужен id, то ты можешь его не указывать. Например есть случаи, когда id в ссылке совпадает с id пользователя, в таком случае @PathVariable не обязателен.